# How do you add an enctype attribute to a FormData() object?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

How do you add an enctype attribute to a FormData() object?

I was building a FormData() object that sent data as well as files. However, despite adding the Content-Type header to the xhr request, the Server could not find the Post.

I added the Content-Type attribute:

```
xhr.open('POST','/post/to/url', true );
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
```

I ultimately just created a  tag with the enctype attribute equal to multipart/form-data and then constructed the FormData object from the  element.

Is there something I'm missing? I would prefer to not have to construct the FormData object from a DOM element.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You do not set the content type when using FormData, it is set automatically when you make the ajax request.
If you set it manually like you did the boundary will not be set and the server will not be able to decode the request.